# Ensure http response goes to $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Tags: http, ip

I want to ensure people who use my site are who they say they are. Not who they say, they say, they are.

How do I ensure my data is going back to the IP given by `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`?

Or is it automatic that the http response is sent there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I ensure my data is going back to the IP given by
>   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?

The client IP is handled by the TCP protocol. The `REMOTE_ADDR` property is populated by the client address of the TCP connection. It's not part of the HTTP protocol. So it is guaranteed that your application is talking to this IP.

This doesn't mean that the IP that you are seeing is the actual IP of the end-user (as attributed for example by his internet provider). There could be proxies or intermediate devices between him and your application. So basically what you will be seeing is the closest IP to your web server in this chain.

Comment: So my server is replying to REMOTE_ADDR then?

Comment: Ok, thanks that answers my question. Silly thing to ask I know, but I just wanted to be sure about this......and yes, I'm aware of the proxy issue.....

Comment: It's never a silly thing to ask, quite the contrary.